# Expression for "a place where you could settle and live without having to ask for permission, pay taxes, ..."

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, terminology, vocabulary

On the History Stack Exchange they were talking about [“white spots”](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23080/when-did-the-last-white-spots-vanish-from-the-earth). Is there a proper expression, a single word, or a phrase for such a place?

> By "white spot" I mean a place where you (if you were so inclined) could 
>       "legally" settle and live in some wilderness as a trapper or farmer without having to ask for permission, pay taxes, etc. (A place where you could get away with anarchy, if you will.)

Comment: What have you yourself found, say in a Google search?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [nothing helpful](https://www.google.com.lb/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=inx5VZbNJImi8QXbroL4CA#q=white+spots+lands+defenition) really

Comment: In the opening sentence, the asker clearly states that the phrase is the author's **nonce** expression for the purpose of the question: "By "white spot" **I mean** a place ..." (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the word you're looking for is probably "[Allodial](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=allodial&use1828=on)". Allodial is an adjective so you'd have to combine it with words like claim, title or land.

However any sovereign government has the eminent claim to its domain and may enact laws to prevent this type of action or simply boot you out because they already owned it. The only truly "unowned" land is that which is also "ungoverened", in which case you'd have to take on all of the responsibilities of a government yourself, including defending it from all other claimants.

Comment: Quite right. And defence might prove a slight problem.

Comment: I think an allod was always understood to be within the territory of one or another feudal state, just not subject to the same level of control; allodial property couldn't be taxed, for example, but the king of France could be expected to defend allods of French subjects against the king of England. In modern international law, I think an allod would simply be a state; Luxemburg and the Vatican might be examples.

Comment: And allody was unique to medieval Europe, while what he's asking about is very different, closer to terra nullius... although probably not quite the same thing...

Comment: Correction: Wikipedia disagrees with me: "Allodial title is related to the concept of land held 'in allodium', or land ownership by occupancy and defense of the land. Historically, much of land was uninhabited and could therefore be held 'in allodium'." So I think allodial actually is the correct term here, obscure as it may be... Upvoting this answer.

Comment: It certainly would be WS2. Also come to think of it, Allodium is probably a better answer since it's a noun used to describe the land itself, which is closer to the requested word, however it is otherwise defined similarly to the definition above in the same dictionary. Also, Nevada, implemented an "Allodial Title" system in 1997, although I do not believe it applied to the same degree as was traditionally meant, since it could be circumstantially lost. I believe it was moreso for buying out the taxes on cheap farmland in advance.  I'm also uncertain if the program is still in effect.